# Negative lookbehind problem

Tags: python, regex

Here is sample text(simplified from original):

```
<start1>
<name="4654">
bla bla bla bla
<tags="bla" model="c">
bla bla bla bla
<start2>
<name="12346">
bla bla bla bla
<tags="bla" model="d">
bla bla bla bla
<start3>
<name="73535">
bla bla bla bla
<tags="bla" model="c">
<start4>
<name="546875">
bla bla bla bla
<tags="bla" model="c">
bla bla bla bla
```

Here is my regex(dot matches new line option is on)

```
name="([\d]+)".+?(?<!start)tags="([^"]+?)" model="c"
```

As you can see there are 4 blocks, but I need to match those with model="c". However `.+?` is capturing more than it needs. Puting negative lookbehind to suppress it did not work... Any idea how can I exclude  block?

Update(to clarify what I want to achieve):

out of sample data I want to match following 3 blocks:

First match

```
<name="4654">
bla bla bla bla
<tags="bla" model="c">
```

Second match

```
<name="73535">
bla bla bla bla
<tags="bla" model="c">
```

Third match

```
<name="546875">
bla bla bla bla
<tags="bla" model="c">
```

Comment: If it is XML, you better use XPath.

Comment: This doesn't look like XML. This is something even worse. :)

Comment: It is not. I've just used xml elements to simplify the sample data.

Comment: Could you kindly explain exactly what the regex is supposed to do?  How much is supposed to be captured?  Looking at the nonfunctional regex doesn't clue us into what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: @Mike Pennington: sure, updated. thanks!

Comment: If you're just using XML to simplify the sample data, how will creating a RegEx to match XML elements help you?

Comment: @Codemonkey: if angle brackets are confusing, I can just remove them. What I am trying to understand is how to engage negative lookbehind in order to exclude the match.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Is it always in this format of (`start`, `name`, `tags`), (`start`, `name`, `tags`), and so on? If so, you can even do without the lookaround.</strike>

```
/<name="(\d+)"[^<]+?<tags="([^"]+?)" model="c">/s
```

That works because you know the next `<` you encounter will be for the immediately following `tags` label. Can we guarantee that's the case, or do we need to be more general to allow for other labels in the mix?

Also, do you need to capture the text after `<tags>` and before the next `<start>`? If so, you could add a little extra to the end for that.

```
/<name="(\d+)"[^<]+?<tags="([^"]+?)" model="c">[^<]*(?!<start)/s
```

Okay, according to your comments, that's not the case. Scratch that, then.

---

*Update*

Okay, how 'bout this then?

```
/<name="(\d+)"(?:(?!<start).)+<tags="([^"]+?)" model="c">/s
```

This actually uses a lookahead, not a lookbehind. A simple lookahead/lookbehind will only assert that a string occurs before or after a block of text, not within. By checking at every character with `((?!str).)+`, you effectively ensure that "str" is not contained *throughout* the text.

It might look confusing that I'm using a lookahead to check for `<start`, whereas a lookbehind for `start` would look like `(?<!start)` instead of `(?!<start)`.
Think `(?!(<start))` versus `(?<!(start))`.

I added `(?: )` just so it wouldn't capture.

Comment: @Wiseguy: the text inbetween name and tag may contain `<` or `>`, should be based on whether `start` keyword is there or not. No, I don't need to capture the netween `<tags>` and `<start>`.

Comment: @Michael See update. Checks for "<start" just in case the word "start" could also appear.

Comment: @Wiseguy: that did a trick, now if you could a little bit elaborate I would be double thankful :)

Comment: @Mike Pennington: I knew there is a way :)

Comment: @Wiseguy: the key part here is capturing(non capturing) group here, still not so obvious, but thanks for your explanation and solution!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a negative lookbehind, try changing your exclusion pattern to make the model="c" non-greedy.

```
name="([\d]+)".+?(?!model=)tags="([^"]+?)" model="c"
```

Comment: it still merges blocks `<start2>` and `<start3>`